# Accessing my method in different class

Tags: android

I have created one class as

```
public class FormActivity extends Activity 
{
    TextView tv =new TextView(this);
    GridLayout gl=new GridLayout(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        paint();
    }

    public void paint()
    {
        tv.setText("In new File");
        gl=(GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gl);
        gl.addView(tv);
    }
}
```

and I want to access the `paint()` method from a different class (java file in same package).
I have tried this:

```
public class FileSystemDemoActivity extends Activity 
{

    FormActivity f1=new FormActivity();
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        f1.paint();
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. The emulator gives unfortunately stopped error. Please help me.

Comment: are you have R.id.gl view on both activity ?

Comment: @AVD:sorry.i have not understood can you give an example?

Comment: means just copy the paint function code in second activity as well.

Comment: You need to define paint() method for each activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sorry.i have not understood can you give an example?
```

you should not try to access the other Activity function as

1- You should not  try to create the instance of other activity in your activity.

2-  findViewById(R.id.gl) is linked with the current activity layout it will search id in that particular activity in which activity code is written.

...

```
 public class FileSystemDemoActivity extends Activity 
        {
        FormActivity f1=new FormActivity();
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            f1.paint();
        }

            public void paint()
            {
                 tv.setText("In new File");
                 gl=(GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gl);
                 gl.addView(tv);
            }

        }
```

Comment: but i don't want paint() method here.the paint() method must be in FormActivity class.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is probably because `gl`is null. You can't access the Activity´s views because it has not been correctly initialized. To start and show FormActivity from another activity use `startActivity()` and its `onCreate` will be called and eventually your ´paint´ method.